# javascript: overriding set interval each time a function is hit?

Tags: javascript

I am getting new expireTimestamps each time a product is added and it hits this function below.  The problem is that the original interval still exists.  I tried running `clearInterval(clockInterval)` at the top of the function but that doesn't do anything  so that the next time the function is hit, it clears it and only has the new interval but that wasn't doing anything.

```
   checkItemExpiry: function(expireTimestamp) {
        let startTime = expireTimestamp;
        let clockInterval = setInterval(() => {
          let currentTime = (new Date()).getTime() / 1000;
            this.convertTime((startTime-currentTime))
        }, 1000);
      },
```

Comment: You'll have to arrange for the timer id to be stored in a variable that's not declared in the local function.

Comment: to use clearInterval you need to intercept the return of setInterval (which is a number), here you push the return in a local function variable so you can't retrieve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let clockInterval;
....
....
...
checkItemExpiry: function(expireTimestamp) {
        let startTime = expireTimestamp;
        clockInterval = setInterval(() => {
          let currentTime = (new Date()).getTime() / 1000;
            this.convertTime((startTime-currentTime))
        }, 1000);
  },
```

I hope you got what the problem was . Its just scoping error .

Comment: yep, just needed to definite the variable out of the global scope.  Thanks!